# Find the Child of a table row

Tags: android

How can I find the child's attributes using the view of the parent.
I have an onclick event in which the tapped row will be removed, now I want to find the Text of its child to delete(reset th variable) the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to the child view you're looking for, then call row.findViewById().

Id's don't have to be unique in the layout tree, but they have to be in the part of tree you are searching in. This way you can give the same id to corresponding views in each row.

Comment: @rahul you can set id dinamically with setId()

Comment: the problem is that when the user clicks the row,all its children will be remove, and in the onclick event how can i find the child id?

Comment: @rahul I suppose the onclick is an `OnClickListener`. If you set it on the `TableRow`, in the `onClick(View v)` `v` is the TableRow (you'll have to cast). If you set the listener on some child, you could just find the `TableRow` that contains it with `v.getParent()`. However you could also use `row.getChildAt(int)`.

Comment: Ok, thanks@bigstones, I am using a generic OnClickListener (the activity class implements OnClickListener), then how can I check whether the clicked component is a tablerow from the list (The UI may contain more than one row)? Now I am doing this by writting a different OnClickListener for deleting the rows.

Comment: @rahul Ok so you're creating these rows dinamically and are setting on them an `OnClickListene`r, which is your activity, so that on click something will happen to the row or its children, right? Then in the `onClick(View v)` you can check if `v instanceof TableRow`, or any other checks you like. `v` is the component to which the listener is attached and that was clicked. If I'm not getting the problem please post your code.